# Why aren't parametrizations equivalent to their "equation form"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the parametrization $(\lambda,t)\mapsto (\lambda t,\lambda t^2,\lambda t^3)$. This is a union of lines (not sure how to visualize it precisely. I think it's a double cone). It doesn't appear that the $x$ or $z$ axis are in this parametrization (if $y$ and $z$ are both zero, so must $x$ be).

However, when you solve the parametrization in terms of $x,y,z$ you obtain the relationship $y^2=xz$. In which the $x$ and $z$ axes are solutions!

Why is this? Is this the closure? If so, how can we relate the closure to the original set?

Comment: The $x$ and $z$ axis are in the closure of the parametrization though: take $\lambda=xt^{-1},t\to0$ and $\lambda=zt^{-3},t\to\infty$ respectively.

Comment: All you have shown is that every point of the form $(\lambda t,\lambda t^2,\lambda t^3)$ satisfies the equation $y^2=xz$. There may be other $x$, $y$ and $z$ which satisfy $y^2=xz$ but which *are not* of the form $(\lambda t,\lambda t^2,\lambda t^3)$. Let $P$ denote the image of the parametrisation, and $E$ the solution set of the equation. You have shown that $P \subseteq E$. In order to show that $P=E$ you would need to also show that $E \subseteq P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say that you "solve" and obtain the relationship $y^2 = xz$ I image you just observed that $(\lambda t^2)^2 = (\lambda t)(\lambda t^3)$ correct?  In this case what you have shown is that the set for which you have a parameterization is a subset of the set of solutions to $y^2 = xz$.  What you have not shown is that every solution of $y^2 = xz$ is covered by the parameterization.  Indeed, as you pointed out, this is not true.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which makes a great deal of sense. I do however, have it from a master mathematician (my professor) that this in fact does give you the closure. Is he just "lucky" that this is true, or is this non-obvious?

Comment: You might need an algebraically closed field for this next statement (meaning you might need to use complex numbers and not real numbers).  But what is true in general is that the image of a parameterization is a "constructible set" whose closure in the Euclidean topology is a variety.  This means there is a set of equations whose zero locus describes the closure, but knowing when you have that particular set and not a set of equations describing something bigger than what you want requires some algebraic geometry, which is a subject that many math students don't see until graduate school.

Comment: p.s. The parameterization has to be by polynomials for what I said to be true.